# Adobe Acrobat Reader after installation shows, "After installing this snap it is recommend to disconnect network interface"

Tags: wine, snap, adobe-reader

When I run Adobe Acrobat, I get a message that starts with

> Note: After installing this snap it is recommend to disconnect network interface so that app does not auto update it. As new versions break the app in wine.

[image: Screen Shot]

It says to run a snap command to disconnect `acrordrdc:network`.
Anybody got any idea what this is all about?

I entered the command as instructed but it keeps coming back with the same popup.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo snap disconnect acrordrdc:network` is the command you're looking for.

Comment: i realize that. It doesn't do anything. The popup keeps coming back. I can't run the application. It hase something to with snap and wine. It was never a problem in 18.04.